# How to exclude specific child with jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML

```
<div class="big-wrap">
  <div class="logoburger">
    <div class="burgermenu">
      <img class="burger" src="/includes/pictures/1452702292_menu-alt.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <div id="search-icon"></div>
      <form class="ui-widget" method="POST" action="../">
        <input id="tags" placeholder="Search.." name="search" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <a class="homepage" href="/">
        <img src="/includes/pictures/Logo.svg" alt="Logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="big-content"></div>
</div>
```

This is my css

```
.pushedoff {
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This is my jquery.

```
$('.burgermenu').click(function() {
  $('.big-wrap').not($'.burgermenu').toggleClass('pushedoff');
}
```

I want the whole .big-wrap to be 'pushedoff' except for an element with class of 'burgermenu' which is a child inside one of the big-wrap children. I tried to use .not() to exclude the .burgermenu, but it does not seems to work. Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot exclude the `.burgermenu` from the styling as it's a child element of `.big-wrap`

Comment: AS above, you are applying the style "above" the element you want to exclude, you may have to rethink your html structure

Comment: also no need for `$` it should be `.not('.burgermenu')` but this wont work since this is child of `'.big-wrap'` you cant exclude a child

Comment: When you call `$('.big-wrap').toggleClass("pushedoff")` you're adding the class to the outer div, not to all of the content inside the div.  So there is no 'except something inside' because you only have one item.  Instead, you can apply `pushedoff` to the individual items *inside* (and not the container), at which point you can exclude the one you want:  `$(".big-wrap>div>div").not(".burgermenu").toggleClass("pushedoff");`  Alternatively, as you're clicking on burgermenu:  `$(this).siblings().toggleClass("pushedoff")` - is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.burgermenu').click(function() {
        $('.logoburger').children('div').not('.burgermenu').toggleClass('pushedoff');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly,

Following is the issue.

You are applying the CSS to parent and you are trying to exclude it in child but as per CSS property inheritance the child element will also inherit the parents property so you cannot do that

I think following snippet will help you to acheive what you want based on your question and comments

```js
$('.burgermenu').click(function() {
  $('.big-wrap div.logoburger').find('div').not('.burgermenu').toggleClass('pushedoff');
});
```

```css
.pushedoff {
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-wrap">
  <div class="logoburger">
    <div class="burgermenu">
      <img class="burger" alt="menu-alt.svg" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food">
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <div id="search-icon"></div>
      <form class="ui-widget" method="POST" action="../">
        <input id="tags" placeholder="Search.." name="search" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <a class="homepage" href="/">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/business" alt="Logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="big-content"></div>
</div>
```